# Drupal 6 or Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal

I am planning to start a course builder web site, and I am trying to take the right choice, wither to choose Drupal 6 or Drupal 7 ??

What I've noticed that most modules are still not ported to Drupal 7 yet.
What are the risk to start developing the website with version 6 ? 
and what features at version 7 that I would lose ??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless there are modules you really need that only exist in Drupal 6 and have no stable version in Drupal 7, I'd say go for Drupal 7.

You'll need to upgrade sooner or later, and starting with 7 from the start will

- Make you more experiences in 7 without first having to learn 6
- Have the site be made for 7, instead of made in 6 and then converted to 7.

Plus, 7 has a few things that vanilla 6 doesn't have.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353545/drupal-7-programming-advancements-differences-from-drupal-6-upgrade-or-wait) that was asked more than a year and a half ago, where 6 was recommended until a stable 7 came out. Drupal is now at 7.8 - should be stable enough for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what makes me hesitating, is that there are a good number of modules dedicated for course building are Drupal 6 versions .. its sad that Drupal 7 dose not support earlier module versions, I think its very expensive and costs allot of time& efforts for the community.

Comment: Drupal 7 contains many improvements, some of which make that earlier modules need to be changed. Authors have had over 2 years to change their modules to be compatible with 7 now - if they haven't finished by now, are you sure you want to use the module?

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 7 comes with new quality of code. Each core module has its own unit tests, which can be used to check the code. It also provides UT module, which makes easier to write test for your custom modules. Unit testing really helps in eliminating bugs from the code.

I'd recommend using Drupal 7. Modules are being ported from version 6 to 7 all the time. The major ones are already there, like views

Answer (score -2):

Drupal 6 has masses of modules and themes, whereas Drupal 7 has a few more features and a slightly better admin panel, it dosen't have that many modules or themes.

Comment: do you mean that its not worthy choosing Drupal 7 ?

Comment: It's very shortsighted to only look at the numbers. Yes, there are more D6 modules, but that number includes modules that have merged into Drupal core, duplicate functionality (often, only the best survives, or modules merge), abandoned modules, and experimental modules (started when there were no [Drupal sandboxes](http://drupal.org/node/1011196) yet). In other words, it's not only about quantity, but also about quality.